# Array is reordered when using $lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have this aggregation:

```
db.getCollection("users").aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "5a708a38e6a4078bd49f01d5"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "user-locations",
      "localField": "locations",
      "as": "locations",
      "foreignField": "_id"
    }
  }
])
```

It works well, but there is one small thing that I don't understand and I can't fix.
In the query output, the `locations` array is **reordered** by `ObjectId` and I really need to keep the original order of data.

Here is how the `locations` array from the `users` collection looks like

```
'locations' : [
     ObjectId("5b55e9820b720a1a7cd19633"), 
     ObjectId("5a708a38e6a4078bd49ef13f")
],
```

And here is the result after the aggregation:

```
'locations' : [
     {
        '_id' : ObjectId("5a708a38e6a4078bd49ef13f"),
        'name': 'Location 2'
     },
     {
        '_id' : ObjectId("5b55e9820b720a1a7cd19633"),
        'name': 'Location 1'
     }
],
```

What am I missing here? I really have no idea how to proceed with this issue.
Could you give me a push?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$lookup`  does not guarantee order of result documents, you can try a approach to manage natural order of document,

- `$unwind` deconstruct `locations` array and add auto `index` number will start from 0,
- `$lookup` with locations
- `$set` to select first element from `locations`
- `$sort` by `index` field in ascending order
- `$group` by `_id` and reconstruct `locations` array

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: "5a708a38e6a4078bd49f01d5" } },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$locations",
      includeArrayIndex: "index"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "user-locations",
      localField: "locations",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "locations"
    }
  },
  { $set: { locations: { $arrayElemAt: ["$locations", 0] } } },
  { $sort: { index: 1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      locations: { $push: "$locations" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4Z8PuTtKRhH)

Answer (score 3):

From this [closed bug report](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32947):

> When using $lookup, the order of the documents returned is not guaranteed. The documents are returned in "natural order" - as they are encountered in the database. The only way to get a guaranteed consistent order is to add a $sort stage to the query.

Basically the way any Mongo query/pipeline works is that it returns documents in the order they were matched, meaning the "right" order is not guaranteed especially if there's indes usage involved.

What you should do is add a `$sort` stage as suggested, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "5a708a38e6a4078bd49f01d5"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "user-locations",
      "let": {
        "locations": "$locations"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$setIsSubset": [
                [
                  "$_id"
                ],
                "$$locations"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            _id: 1 // any other sort field you want.
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "locations",
    }
  }
])
```

You can also keep the original `$lookup` syntax you're using and just `$unwind`, `$sort` and then `$group` to restore the structure.

Comment: Using `$sort` is not preserving the original indexes of the array (the one from the `users` collection). If I unwind the result after the `$lookup` stage, I think that I'm going to have the same ordering issues. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to sort, in your answer it looked like you want to sort the `user-locations` results. regardless you need a `$sort` stage to guarantee order on whatever field you want in a certain order, it's up to you to decide which fields sortage gives the expected result.

Comment: I need to keep the indexes (same order) as of the `locations` array - the one from the `users` collection, because after the `$lookup` the new array (also called locations), which contains the joined data is inverted - it is automatically ordered by `ObjectId`. Maybe my question is misleading.

Comment: That's what I understood, why is the answer provided not doing it?

Comment: No, it is still ordered by the `_id` => older to newest.

Comment: The `$sort` with `1` is ascending order and with `-1` is descending order, did you check the results or are you assuming the order is wrong?
https://mongoplayground.net/p/lCGytOohpm7

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.getCollection("users").aggregate([
                {
                  "$match": {
                    "_id": "5a708a38e6a4078bd49f01d5"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "$lookup": {
                    "from": "user-locations",
                    "localField": "locations",
                    "foreignField": "_id",
                    "let": {
                        indexArray: "$locations",
                    },
                    "pipeline": [
                        {
                            "$addFields": {
                               "index": { "$indexOfArray": ["$$indexArray", "$_id"] }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "$sort": { "index": 1 }
                        }
                    ],
                    "as": "locations",
                  }
                }
              ])
```

Comment: Answers should not contain code only, it would be nice if you could edit your answer and provide some explanation about the code